# "Down there"? When to use?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I sometimes see this phrase. I'm not sure when to use it, is it about a place that is geographically low?

For example (taken from [Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/down+there)):

> It's not going to be nice **down there**.
>
> She's **down there** crying.
>
> It's nice to be **down there** and not watch TV.

Could it be used interchangeably with "Over there"?

Comment: It depends on the broader context.  Could mean a lower floor of the building.  Could mean "downtown".  Could mean a "mean" location.  Could mean Australia.

Comment: @HotLicks Oi! Or maybe, [Oi! Oi! Oi!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussie_Aussie_Aussie,_Oi_Oi_Oi) :)

Comment: @HotLick What does "mean location“ means? Could I use 'down there' to describe any place on earth that is not right here? Is it about style?

Comment: @SunnySideDown - The wrong side of the tracks, the slums, etc.  Anywhere that is looked down upon.

Comment: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mean): adjective 3 *(especially of a place) poor in quality and appearance; shabby.*

Comment: Can also mean a little way south (not necessarily the other side of the world) as in *We're going down to Brighton to see my parents this weekend, then up to York next week to see hers*.

Comment: @Minty - Yep, and "down in New Orleans" (or maybe "down in Norlins") would be quite idiomatic in much of the US.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing at all special about this collocation.  You need to learn to see this as just one instance of a far more general form.

It’s exactly like any of *over, under, up, down, around, near* (and others) combined with *here* or *there*.

The first element is an adverb of location and the second element is one of the two (or three) locative deictics *here* or *there* — or possibly in some speakers, also *yonder* for a more distant position than *there* would refer to.

Comment: Is there a reason why this question is considered better suited to ELU than to ELL (where I'm not at all sure it would be considered acceptable)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I had initially planned to make my middle paragraph's sentence a comment, then realized I was answering in comments and thought better of it. Would you prefer this were migrated to ELL?

Comment: I don't think it's properly formulated. Does 'there' really matter? Wouldn't 'down in Devon/Florida' / 'down s/South' be equally relevant (which I'm pretty sure makes this a duplicate)? OP's examples lack context and are no help. // I feel uneasy about giving 'answers' in comments, but more uneasy about giving answers in 'answers' when I've also close-voted. I feel that adding an answer endorses the question's validity, so will send out mixed messages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *There* seems essential to me in some contexts. I would never say *I ate the food down*, but *I ate the food down* ***there***. (At least, not if I was talking about eating food at some place.) And the first two example sentences in the question seem ungrammatical to me without *there*, while the third changes meaning without it.

Comment: @Jason Bassford 'there' is merely a placeholder for an antecedent. 'down in Texas / down in the lounge ...' would do equally as well. I fail to see that this question is valid here. / Asking 'why "down there" and not not "down in there" for "down in Texas"?' could be fair game, but this isn't what OP is asking, in my view.