# Down there vs over there (British)

Tags: british-english

How you differentiate between Down there and Over there? 
Let's suppose, two persons walking up the road and one says to other by pointing out the place, "They live down there". What if he would have said "They live over there"

I'm confused with their use. Also, "walking up to library " and "walking down to the library". What's the difference?

More things like "coming in", "coming over". Example,  What time he came in? 
What time he came over?

Thanks!

Comment: In my British English, "**down**" has the approximate meaning of "along" and would be used to indicate a path, road, or street (or in some circumstances, a river) which can be taken to arrive at the house. This contrasts with "**over**" that indicates that the speaker is talking about a general direction, often without a specifically dedicated direct route. e.g. across those fields, on the other side of that road/bridge, that river, etc., i.e. something that creates an obstacle between the speaker and the house.

Comment: @Greybeard Could you please add some real examples and reply as Answer so I can vote for that.

Comment: See [Do I travel “up” or “down” to London from north of the city?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23545/do-i-travel-up-or-down-to-london-from-north-of-the-city) Also many similar questions on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @user11702680  A: (Speaker points to a road) "Their house is down there." -- B: (Speaker points across a river) "Their house is over there." -- Wrong - C: (Speaker points at a house on the other side of the road) "Their house is down there."

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Down there"? When to use?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/499800/down-there-when-to-use) Also addressed in [Do I travel up or down to London from north of the city?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23545/do-i-travel-up-or-down-to-london-from-north-of-the-city). // Note that if there are obvious hills involved, 'up' and 'down' would almost always default to their primary spatial senses.

Comment: Also, [Collocation with over / down out {+ here / there}](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222828/collocation-with-over-down-out) was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The library question depends on whether it is uphill or downhill from where you are (although _walk up to_ can also mean _approach on foot_ in some contexts).